# Printing 32 different 32x32 matrices per second with control signals

Tags: c

I am trying to implement a control signal which adds a value to each element of the matrix and print the whole matrix with the change.

Basically, I am simulating this by adding 1 into first element of the matrix (`matrix[0][0]`) and then control signal will add 1 into each element of the matrix and then print it.

The problem is, it should print 32 matrices per second with 32 changes. Like below:

```
1 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0

1 1 0
0 0 0
0 0 0

1 1 1
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

... and so on.

First I tried it with a 3x3 matrix and it is printing 9 matrices per second correctly. But when I try to change it to 32x32, it takes 3-4 seconds to print nearly 10 matrices, so it is much slower.

Here is my code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int matrix[3][3] = {0};
int row=0;
int col=0;
int i, j, k, l;
int seccount = 0;


void value_changer();
static void catch_signal(int signal)
{
        for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
                for(j=0; j<3; j++)
                {
                       if(i==0 && j==0)
                       {
                              //continue;
                              for(k=0; k<3; k++)
                              {
                                      for(l=0; l<3; l++)
                                      {
                                              printf("%d ", matrix[k][l]);
                                      }
                                      printf("\n");
                               }
                             printf("\n");

                       }
                     else
                      {
                             matrix[i][j] += 1;
                             for(k=0; k<3; k++)
                             {
                                    for(l=0; l<3; l++)
                                    {
                                            printf("%d ", matrix[k][l]);
                                    }
                                    printf("\n");
                            }
                            printf("\n");
                    }
            }
    }
}

void value_changer()
{
       matrix[0][0] += 1;
       raise(SIGINT);
       printf("***************** Seconds: %d ********************\n",seccount++);
 }

int main()
{
     //value_changer();
    if (signal(SIGINT, catch_signal) == SIG_ERR)
    {
            fputs("An error occurred while setting a signal handler.\n", stderr);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    puts("Raising the signal.");

    while(1)
    {
            //raise(SIGINT);
            value_changer();
            sleep(1);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

First of all, am I doing this correctly or missing something?
Second, is this control signal correct?
Third, is there any other (better and more efficient) way to perform the mentioned action?

Note: given program is 3x3 matrix and 9 matrix per second with control signal.

Comment: which header for `sleep()`?and `sleep(1)`(or my guess `Sleep(1)`) is sleeping for 1ms?

Comment: Sleep(1) will make it sleep for 1 second... `unsigned sleep(unsigned seconds);` .. I dont have errors in my code. Its just that I cant achieve 32 matrices printed in one second.. It takes 4-5 seconds..

Answer (score 0):

Output to a terminal is slow. I suggest you create the data in memory and do a single output operation. I would also suggest you construct the data *outside* the signal handler, and only do the output there.

---

```
char buffer[4096];

static void catch_signal(int)
{
    printf(buffer);
}

void value_changer(void)
{
    char temp[32];

    /* "Reset" buffer */
    buffer[0] = '\0';

    /* Do whatever "output" operations needed */
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(matrix) / sizeof(matrix[0]); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(matrix[i]) / sizeof(matrix[i][0]); j++)
        {
            snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp) - 1, "%d ", matrix[i][j]);
            strcat(buffer, temp);
        }
        strcat(buffer, "\n");
    }

    /* Do the other stuff */
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Can you suggest this with some sample code.. I've tried something like buffer but dont know how to verify whether the output to the terminal is slow or my program has some problem....

Comment: @HirenPandya Those nested loops, do them instead in `value_changer`, but instead of doing `printf` to output it to the terminal, do e.g. `snprint` to print to a buffer. Then in the signal handler all you have to do is a single `printf` call to output the buffer.

Comment: Thats great.. But I need some sample which can show me the exact working of printing the buffer from signal handler..

Comment: One more thing.. printing 32 matrix from buffer will require the buffer to be declared as buffer[1024][32].. Do you think this is correct or is there any better way according to you ??

Comment: @HirenPandya Made an _incomplete_ example, just to show the principle.

Comment: Using your code, performance degrades.. Its takes too much time for the compilation of the program.. What is the reason ?? How can I find it..? I mean, I've done for 3x3 matrix.. If I take 32x32 thn it might cause the system to behave strangely...